# Thoughts on building a brace for a heavy chandelier?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, joists

I need to build a brace to support [this light fixture](https://www.etsy.com/listing/640941292) in my dining room.

[image]

The eyelet screws on either end should be attached to the existing ceiling joists. However, mine run opposite the direction that I need them to. My plan is to cut 2x8 supports and fasten them between the joists, then attach the eyelet screws into the new supports.

I am considering running a length of metal rod through the new supports so that I can hold it more firmly in place using washers and nuts on either end. Overkill? Would this add any structural benefit or just wishful thinking?

Do I need to leave a gap at the top of the supports for airflow? I am concerned about trapping heat from the electrical box in the cavity that I'll be creating. If a gap is needed, how much space should I leave at the top?

Any other concerns for mounting a very heavy lighting fixture?

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Clarifying one proposed plan:

[image]

Comment: How much does that fixture weigh? I think 2x8 blocking is a little bit overkill and metal rods are unnecessary. Are you sure that the eyelet screws are intended to connect directly to the joists and carry the load? The eyelets don't look to be in the right configuration to do that in most cases.  Can you post additional pictures of the reverse side of the base plate and the location in the attic (and the electrical box location) where you want to mount this?

Comment: @GregNickoloff The 48" beam weighs about 80 lbs. I believe you're right; the eyelet screws are too short to go through the (wood) base plate, drywall, and into the joists. The base plate is the same on both sides with only a cutout for the wiring. The dining room is on our first floor with a bedroom, not attic, above it. Picture of the current situation has been added to the original post. Thank you!

Comment: "running a length of metal rod through the new supports " - unnecessary, decent construction screws are good for nearly 1000lbs pull out force apiece.

Comment: Honestly, consider digging out 3/4 of the mass by emptying the center of the wooden beams.  That's a LOT of weight to suspend over people.  Noone will see down into it.

Comment: I'd definitely ensure that this could also support the weight of someone hanging on it. just in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could attach blocking to the joists on both sides of the existing electrical box and bracing, etc.

By attaching the blocking vertically, you will maximize the weight capacity, but by attaching horizontally you can provide a larger area to "hit" with the mounting hardware. Both orientations should support the weight adequately. Sections of 2x4 mounted vertically would easily support the weight, but you might use 2x6 or 2x8 if you mount it horizontally to maximize the surface area.

Make sure the blocking is as tight as it can be between the joists (within reason) and the ends are nice and square, etc. then fasten with 3-3.5" construction screws through the joists. Mount the blocking so that the bottom surface is flush with the bottom surface of the joists.
[image: sketch of joists and added blocking, etc.]

Attach the "base plate" of the lighting fixture through the drywall to the blocking. You can use ["old fashioned" looking lag screws](https://www.oldwestiron.com/collections/lag-screws-lag-bolts) to attach the block. These are available at BigBox, etc. and will match the ironwork on the fixture.

[image: Stylized fastener example]
Example fastener

Comment: This was intuitively what I had planned on doing. I'm glad to see that it's a suitable solution. I wish I could give points to (or buy a  for) everyone who responded because all answers helped me think about this problem better.

Comment: I'm always up for a beer! Next time you're in Toledo.... You can up-vote everything for a few points to everyone...if you haven't already.

Comment: @Yuck This is a very good solution, when Greg mentions construction screws, pick a good brand like Spax. The rated shear load will be printed on the packaging, so with the load divided by 12 screws, you can see just how much overkill you are applying to support your 100lb fixture!

Comment: @GlenYates: FYI, shear strength is not what holds anything up in this situation. The shear load on the screws will be pretty much 0. Frictional force between the joists and the blocking is what holds everything up, the screws are just there to ensure that that frictional preload is present. Shear strength in many screws is pretty miserable compared to their their tensional capacity, but that's OK. This is also why several of us have mentioned to make sure the blocking is square and fits snugly before tightening in place.

Comment: I ended up doing this with one 2x8 on either side of the box. Base plate will be mounted parallel to the joists. The 2x8 pieces are attached through the joist with 3 Simpson Strong-Tie #10x3-1/2" screws. As mentioned I don't believe these are actually providing load bearing support. I will use 1 3/8x4-1/2" screw eye to hold each side of the beam. These are rated at 155 lbs each (DuraSteel part number 320133).

Answer (score 4):

*Update after seeing the fixture image:*

There's no need to bolt the box to the support framing other than to secure it in position. Nothing hangs from the box (so it doesn't even need to be fan-rated). I would still run the 2x10 over the box, and I'd add blocking on each side of the box to bring it down flush with the adjacent joists. This will give you solid backing for the fixture board and/or the eye screws.

```
|  |__________________________________|  |<-- joist
|  |__________________________________|<-|--- backing board
|__|____________||_____||_____________|__|
                   ^                ^
                   light box        spacer block
```

A 2x10 spanning just ~15" will carry that load without breaking a sweat. It's all a matter of good fastening.

---

*Earlier answer:*

I would run a 2x6 or larger, laid flat, over the box. Secure it with at least three 3" gold construction screws or two 1/4"x3" lag screws at each end. Bolt the box to it. (If the box you have now isn't fan-rated, upgrade it. You need the mounting screw holes for the fixture to be robust enough for the job.)

---

Heat escaping electrical boxes isn't generally a concern. If it was, all boxes would be required to have clearance or insulation. If enough heat is being generated to cause a safety issue, something's badly wrong with the wiring.

---

*Unsolicited protip:* Next time you cut a hole in drywall for repairs, leave an inch or two extending past the adjacent framing. This way you can float backing for the patch without having to fasten it to the existing framing. It's much quicker and doesn't require careful positioning.

---

*Engineering point of interest:* The chains on that fixture hold approximately twice the weight you might think. This is because of their angles. Whereas a vertical chain would hole more or less half the weight of the fixture, they now hold roughly the entire weight of it... *each*. Load force increases exponentially as the angle strays from vertical. If you're selecting chain yourself, be sure that it's up to the task.

Comment: Thanks, I added a photo of a 2x10 to illustrate my understanding of what you're suggesting. Would I remove the existing brace and support straps? Seems I'd need to in order to fit the 2x10 (or even 2x6) in there. And would I just screw the box to the 2x10 once it's in place? What prevents the 2x10 from buckling in the middle?

Comment: @Yuck the cross bracing is designed to prevent the joists from twisting. When you put your 2x in there, you'll be adding significant stiffness that will help prevent this twisting.

Comment: Answer revised now that I can see the fixture.

Comment: Instead of using the backing board, could I just use a 2x6 on either side of the box flush with the bottom of the joist, securing those with lag screws. Then attach the base plate using the eye screws through the drywall ceiling and into those 2x6? It seems like that would be simpler as long as it's still sufficient for that weight.

Comment: Now you're carrying all the weight on what's essentially a hinge. Those blocks can flex downward, putting huge force on the screws. It would probably hold, but it's nowhere near as strong.

Comment: @Yuck: the 2x10 won't buckle because it's solid wood. You could hang a pickup truck from a 2x10 spanning 16" ignoring the capacity of the joists. If instead of a 2x10, you had a 2x6, oriented vertically above the box, it would be even stronger. Make sure whatever you put between the two joists fits as snugly as possible before you screw it in.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, maybe it's not clear. I intend to run the base plate parallel to the joists. This is based on how the dining room table has to fit inside the dining room. It seems like this answer assumes the base plate will run perpendicular to the joists. Or am I misunderstanding? Does this change anything?

Comment: @Yuck -  You're on the right track now. Mount the 2x between the joists oriented vertically and even with the bottom edge of the joists, and attach the base plate to that using lag bolts. (Without seeing the "eye screws" in detail, I doubt they're long enough) You can find the lag screws styled to match the rest of the ironwork on the fixture.

Comment: @Yuck: what are the dimensions of the base plate?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do personally:

[image: Support]

I would get a 2x8 or larger, cut it to fit the width, cut a notch to fit the box, the fasten that between the joists. Make sure you cut the width of that to fit as snugly as possible without having to excessively force it in, gentle tapping with your fist is ideal. Put 3 or so screws such as [these DeckMate screws](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DECKMATE-9-x-2-1-2-in-Star-Drive-Flat-Head-Deck-Screw-5-lbs-115924/313358328) on each side. The resulting structure will be sufficiently rigid that the joists will come down before the light support does. Secure the upper board with the eyelets to this 2x8 with similar screws with the right aesthetics, such as [these low profile screws](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FastenMaster-3-16-in-2-7-8-in-HeadLok-Star-Drive-Flat-Head-Wood-Screw-12-Pack-FMHLGM278-12/202618112). Secure the box with the same screws you use to secure the support.

The notching of the bottom of this support is a non-issue, even a 2x4 spanning the joists would be enough to support the light fixture. A notched 2x6 is going to have plenty of leftover rigidity, 2x8 or larger just increases the already-plenty safety factor.

Definitely use a fan rated box, as maybe 20 years in the future you'll want a new aesthetic and might put a fan in or something else that needs to be supported entirely by the box.

Edit: if you are mounting the base plate parallel to the joists, then just do this with two 2x6s in the right position to place the screws through the baseplate in attractive locations, and forget about the notching. Again, even a pair of 2x4s is more than enough for the task.

If mounting perpendicular to the joists, and the position of the eyelets are such that they are outside the joist space where the box is, then it would make sense to do the above, with a support on each side of the box's space.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running a 2x header between the joist and level with the junction box. Then hanging the fixture on the eyebolts that fastened on the 2x. It will be much sturdy.

[image] [image][image]

Comment: I wouldn't do this with bolts, as it will be such a pain in the neck when you want/need to remove it. Screws of some sort are a much better bet, as they can be withdrawn without ripping out the whole ceiling.

Comment: @MikeBrockington THe solution is simple, see the updated sketch.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second/lower nut?  (I would still go with an eye-bolt with a wood-screw thread on it - so much simpler.)

Comment: @MikeBrockington The top nut carries the weight, the bottom nuts to prevent the bolt from wobbling.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Yes, the screw is simpler for the majority of works, but for hanging heavyweight and movable overhead items, there is a chance the screw may split the wood due to its large size, and pull out from the wood while shaking back and forth during an earthquake event. My philosophy for such construction is always "better safer than sorry".